# Plot a line on the complex plane knowing one point and its orientation

Tags: plotting, complex

I want to draw a line on the complex plane which begins at $0.4+0.1i$, and with an angle of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with respect to the real axis. Is there a simple way to do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: `Plot[ x - 0.3, { x, 0.4, 1 }]`

Comment: In fact I would like to generalize this for every theta and point! but thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

of course! :) ... but I'm going to give you some food for thought

```
v = 4/10 + 1/10 I;
ParametricPlot[Through[{Re, Im}[v]] + {Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4]} t, {t, 0, 2}, 
               AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That sounds really good, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @JulienRoussillon Of course that isn't the easiest way, but you aren't a freshman. So I thought about introducing a few useful tricks.Hope you can follow them

Answer (score 5):

Of course, you can also use the new `InfiniteLine[]` primitive:

```
Graphics[InfiniteLine[ReIm[0.4 + 0.1 I], ReIm[Exp[I π/4]]]]
```

An alternative also uses `AngleVector[]`:

```
Graphics[InfiniteLine[ReIm[0.4 + 0.1 I], AngleVector[π/4]]]
```

Generalization should be straightforward.

---

Here is a visualization courtesy of m_goldberg:

```
With[{z0 = (4 + 1 I)/10, θ = π/4},
  Graphics[{
    InfiniteLine[ReIm[z0], ReIm[Exp[I θ]]],
    Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[ReIm[z0]]},
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    Frame -> True]]
```

[image: line]